# Обновился до CentOs 7 и потерял сервер. Что делать?

Tags: centos, загрузка, обновление

Обновился до CentOs 7 по [инструкции](http://kb.h1host.ru/article/view?id=206).
После перезагрузки сервер потерялся. Подключил монитор и увидел следующую ошибку:
[image: ошибка сервера]
При этом мигают лампочки на клавиатуре и она не реагирует ни на скролл лок ни на shift - pgup ни на ctrl - pgup чтобы посмотреть что там в начале ошибки.

По идее проблема в файловой системе. У меня на загрузке зеркальный рейд, который раньше определялся как md0 и md1, но сейчас он определяется как md126 и md127. Правда в fstab диски записаны через UUID.

Если зайти в rescue и посмотреть список дисков, то мы видим следующую картину:
[image: диски]
Мне кажется странным то, что смотнировано как /dev/md126 без всяких слайсов.

При загрузке в rescue видно вот что:
[image: rescue]

Буду счастлив любым советам, кроме полной переустановки системы.

UPD. Нашел в корпусе сервера бумажку, которую писал когда делал разметку диска:
[image: разметка диска]

UPD2. Общими усилиями выяснили, что до fstab дело не доходит и все тормозится где-то на стадии загрузки. ПОэтому добавляю еще grub.conf
[image: grub.conf]

UPD3. Смог увидеть начало ошибки:
[image: начало ошибки]

Comment: что-то с диском не в порядке на последнем снимке. такой странный uuid упомянут в fstab, в конфигурации загрузчика или в initrd? сверьтесь с существющими идентификаторами (отображаются программой `blkid`). // с предыдущим linux-ом система загружается?

Comment: А как загрузить с предыдущим? Есть такая возможность? Я, при загрузке, ничего такого не вижу.

Comment: Сверил fstab с данными blkid. Все верно.

Comment: что верно? раздел с таким uuid-ом, как на третьем снимке, в системе имеется? он должен монтироваться куда-нибудь? он удачно монтируется?

Comment: md0 превратился в md126 и монтируется, md2 превратился в md127 и тоже монтируется, swap монтируется. md1, и md3 не поменяли имен, их uuid совпадают с uuid в фстаб, но они не монтируются.

Comment: я спрашиваю про пятую строку на снимке под надписью «при загрузке в rescue».

Comment: Такого девайса нет нигде. В fstab он точно не прописан. Я не знаю откуда он берется.

Comment: в первом комментарии я указал ещё два (помимо /etc/fstab в корневом разделе) места, где он может упоминаться.

Comment: Да. Я сейчас проверил и понял, что до загрузки fstab вообще не доходит. Ошибка вылетает сразу же после перезагрузки. Про остальные места можно подробнее? Я о них не знаю.

Comment: если в качестве загрузчика программы *linux* используется программа *grub*, то (обычно) конфигурацию следует искать где-нибудь в `/boot/grub/`. файлы с *initrd* лежат (обычно) в каталоге `/boot`. т.к. по сути *initrd* — это архив «минимальной» корневой файловой системы, в нём также присутствует (обычно) файл `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: В папке boot было пусто. Я подмонтировал родной boot в другую папку, появилось. там из того, что можно редактировать, только /boot/grub/grub.conf Я посмотрел, там uuid корня правильный. Но остальные параметры вообще не пойму. Куча всяких значений. МОжет тоже сфоткать и прикрепить?

Comment: текст всегда лучше показывать текстом.

Comment: Я не могу текстом т.к. сервер в rescue и к нему нет доступа. Добавил еще картинку. Меня там смущают rd_MD_UUID. Не знаю что это.

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос с ошибкой из первого изображения был решен. Оказалось, что в grub.conf не была прописана строчка initrd.

В моем случае это:

```
initrd /initramfs-3.10/0-229.el7.x86_64.img
```